# Alfresco bpmn custom executionListener

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I want create custom execution listener to set value to textfield on start form. Also i need send email to list of people. But when i add execution elements to workflow i catch exception:

`<b>org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 10080001 Script url /api/workflow/activiti$LegalDocFlow/formprocessor does not support the method GET</b>`

I add to bpmn only extension elements:

```html
<process id="LegalDocFlow" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true" name="LegalProcessSchema" processType="None">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:executionListener event="start" activiti:delegateExpression="${StartListener}"/>
            <activiti:executionListener event="end" activiti:delegateExpression="${EndListener}"/>
        </extensionElements>
....
```

My listeners look like this:

```
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.ExecutionListener;
import org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.DelegateExecutionScriptBase;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("StartListener")
public class StartListener implements ExecutionListener {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(StartListener.class);

    public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CreateListener");
    }
}
```

Wat i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I replace listener to startEvent:

```
<startEvent id="alfrescoStartevent1" name="Alfresco start" activiti:formKey="dfrwr:startProcesstask" >
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="${StartListener}"/>
            <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="${EndListener}"/>
        </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
```

And it's work!